# How to solve unmet dependencies in ubuntu 14.04 while installing mysql-server

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-14.04

On Ubuntu 14.04, I got this error while running `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`:

> ```
>     Building dependency tree       
>     Reading state information... Done
>     You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>     The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>      linux-image-extra-3.19.0-49-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic but it is not going to be installed
>      linux-image-extra-3.19.0-51-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-51-generic but it is not going to be installed
>      linux-image-extra-3.19.0-56-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-56-generic but it is not going to be installed
>      linux-image-generic-lts-vivid : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-56-generic but it is not going to be installed
>                                      Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
>      mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
>     E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
> ```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

If I run`df -m`, it shows:

```
Filesystem                    1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/sampledomain--vg-root   1811898 15709   1704127   1% /
none                                  1     0         1   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                              32200     1     32200   1% /dev
tmpfs                              6443     1      6442   1% /run
none                                  5     0         5   0% /run/lock
none                              32211     0     32211   0% /run/shm
none                                100     0       100   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                           236   227         0 100% /boot
```

Answer (score 0):

My /boot partition was full too just doing a plain old

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This post ([How To Fix A Full /boot Partition on Linux](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1974-how-to-fix-a-full-boot-partition-on-linux)) helped me clear some of the obsolete linux images off it.

The following may not be directly relevant to you, but after some deletions, I did

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The output also suggested

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Which also trimmed my /boot to 35% used.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you go on and try as is the apt-get says ? that may do the trick ..
Connect your system to internet
Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

let the system do its stuff then,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I am getting another error while running 2nd command: 

_dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-56-generic_3.19.0-56.62~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-56-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-56-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)_

Comment: give your "df -m" output

Comment: I have edited my question. I guess /boot is used 100%, so it is showing error. But how to increase the /boot memory from remote?

Comment: Try getting some space into your boot directory, and then try it.